# Right implementation of cron job in phalcon

Tags: php, cron, phalcon

What is the right way of implementing cron jobs using phalcon php framework?

I've been trying [the Sid\Phalcon\Cron library](https://github.com/SidRoberts/phalcon-cron)
and reading the docs over and over again and I can't figure out how to get the library running.

I got a Phalcon CLI task running Ok, the idea is create a cron job to execute that task.

This is my code:

```
        $this->app->di->set(
            "cron_notify",
            function () {
                $cron = new \Sid\Phalcon\Cron\Manager();
                 $cron->add(
                    new \Sid\Phalcon\Cron\Job\System(
                        "* 8 * * *",
                        "php console.php mytask action"
                    )
                );
            });
```

What else I need to do? I also attach the console to the DI with:

```
$console = new \Phalcon\Cli\Console();
$di->setShared("console", $console);
```

I also tried adding the cron this way:

```
$cron->add(
            new \Sid\Phalcon\Cron\Job\Phalcon(
                "0 * * * *",
                [
                    "task"   => "task",
                    "action" => "action",
                    "params" => "params"
                ]
            )
        );
```

With the console object attached and calling my phalcon task, but it's not working either.

Comment: `But it's not working.` meaning?

Comment: The cron is not being set. I don't get any errors or exceptions, and just the process of my task is not executing

Comment: Have you tried to figure out how does DI (Dependency Injection) work in Phalcon?

Comment: It's a container of dependecies, right?, To integrate different components in the framework, and for accessing them across the app. How should I implement or define the dependency in my app to make the library work?

Comment: Is there a method I shoul call? I mean, I'm just defining the dependency but not starting the service as well

Comment: Did you eventually figure this out?

Comment: @blackbird No. I ended up using a ssh script to create the cron (phalcon cli task) and I invoked the script from a phalcon controller via shell_exec (passing some parameters). I can send you the implementation if you want